# Chrome doesn't respect the "visuallyhidden" class on tables

Tags: css, google-chrome, html5boilerplate

The `visuallyhidden` class, used by HTML5 Boilerplate, doesn't completely hide `<table>`s in Chrome.

```
.visuallyhidden
{
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

To clarify: the table is invisible in Chrome but it takes up physical space and can cause unwanted scrollbars etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not totally sure which part is causing problems for Chrome but setting `display: block;` is a good enough fix for my purposes.